# llamar una columna como variable

Tags: sql-server

un cordial saludo para todos
estoy desarrollando un procedimiento almacenado que me permita ejecutar en un ciclo while la actualización de los índices de una tabla :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Plan_Mantenimiento
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    CREATE TABLE #idx_temp
    (
Table_Name varchar (60),
Index_Name varchar (60),
Index_type varchar (60),
Fragmentation_Percentage float
    )

insert into #idx_temp
    SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(IDX.OBJECT_ID) AS Table_Name, 
IDX.name AS Index_Name, 
IDXPS.index_type_desc AS Index_Type, 
IDXPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent  Fragmentation_Percentage
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) IDXPS 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes IDX  ON IDX.object_id = IDXPS.object_id 
AND IDX.index_id = IDXPS.index_id 
where avg_fragmentation_in_percent >=60 and IDX.name is not null
ORDER BY Fragmentation_Percentage
```

de aquí todo bien salvo porque las variables no me están acumulando las columnas:

```
/*****************|declaración de variables|********************/  

    declare @tabla_nom varchar(60)
    declare @idx_nom varchar(60)

/***************************************************************/

while exists (select top 1 Table_Name,Index_Name ,Index_type,Fragmentation_Percentage  from #idx_temp)
begin
select top 1  Index_Name ,Table_Name    from #idx_temp 
ALTER INDEX  @idx_nom=Index_Name  ON  @tabla_nom=Table_name REORGANIZE WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION = ON );
delete from #idx_temp where Index_Name = @idx_nom
end


drop table #idx_temp
```

al ejecutarlo me dice que la columna `Table_Name` no existe o no tengo permisos, además de que el alter me tira error al llamar las variables

que tengo mal?

pd: este es el error

```
Msg 1088, Level 16, State 9, Line 49
Cannot find the object "Table_name" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Comment: Donse estas asiganandole valores?

Comment: ALTER INDEX  @idx_nom=Index_Name  ON  @tabla_nom=Table_name REORGANIZE WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION = ON );  esta linea de código es la que me genera el problema como dije antes tuve que editar esto de nuevo ya que no se guardó bien perdón

Comment: Podes agregar los errores que te salen, con el codigo de error?

Comment: Que estas tratando de hacer? un mantenimiento de indices?

Comment: exactamente, eso trato de hacer pero como son tantos indices decidí hacerlo de tal manera

Comment: gente muchas gracias por sus aportes, ya lo pude solucionar por medio de un query dinámico dentro del while y asignando las variables en el select top